# Mapping the values of a string union type to be the keys of an objec type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given a string union type:

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'pear'
```

How would I write a type declaration to **map** the above to an object type which has those string values as its keys (with all of their values, say, as strings)?

A type, which if I were to manually define, would look like this:

```
type FruitObject = {
  apple:string;
  banana:string;
  pear:string;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the predefined type [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'pear'

type FruitObject = Record<Fruit, string>
// {
//   apple:string;
//   banana:string;
//   pear:string;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigcgIZjAGwkygB8sAjbAO2u2LM0mzkwFgAoD0SWRFAeXIArCAGNUGAEpiA9nAAmAHnjJgAGigBnYHCRUA5gD4OAehNQA3qfNQouAhABc23QYDc121Eo0aznXr6HuxmXkxw-q5BngC+QA)